# Sql search error, needing syntax explanation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need some help to create a search using 2 tables, its probably a syntax error.

In the table respostas I need the date from aquestion_id e user_id only from the user $logado.

From table questions I need the question from pergunta and question_id that needs to be created only from ids not listened in aquestion_id.
For test I made 4 questions, but its not working.

The question comes randomly but the $logado looks not included in search because its shows 0 in `echo $exibir['user_id'];`.

Also all questions come randomly but dont stop to show after answered.

```
<?php
$sqluser = "SELECT a.aquestion_id, a.user_id, b.pergunta, b.question_id FROM respostas a INNER JOIN questions b ON a.aquestion_id != b.question_id WHERE a.user_id = '$logado' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$executarquest=mysqli_query($conuser, $sqluser);
while ($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($executarquest)){
  if ($exibir['question_id'] > 0)
  {
    $guarda = ($exibir['question_id']);
      echo '<b>Quesion ID: </b>';
    echo $exibir['question_id'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $exibir['pergunta'];
    echo $exibir['user_id'];

  }
  else{
    header('location:/quiz/acabou.php');
  }
}
?>
```

Appreciate any help, and sorry again for post the first time in Portuguese.

Comment: On a side note: Alias names should be mnemonic, like q for question and r for response. Alias names shall increase a query's readability, but names like a, b, c decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

First off all: The query should work syntactically, but I doubt it returns what you want. You are randomly picking one of the user's answers along with some unrelated question.

As to `WHERE a.user_id = '$logado'`: `'$logado'` is a string. It contains a dollar sign and the word logado. MySQL wants to compare the numeric `user_id` with it, so it converts your string to a number. This should better fail with an error in my opinion, but MySQL rather returns 0 instead. This is what you are seeing in the results: An answer given by user 0 and a question.

I suppose you want to use a variable instead:

```
"...WHERE a.user_id = ".$logado." ORDER ..."
```

(And then you may have to fix your query to return something meaningful.)